# Discord.js Embed Issues

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Trying to send embed crashes and logs out with error:

"RangeError: RichEmbed field values may not be empty."

I've tried adding multiple checks to see if anything is not unidentified and is causing the issue, but nothing seems to fix it.

The embed is fully sent, but in the end it breaks and crashes the bot.

```
    client.on("messageUpdate",(oldMsg,newMsg) =>{
    if(newMsg.author.bot && !newMsg.guild){return}
    //console.log(oldMsg.content,newMsg.content)
    messageEditEmbed(oldMsg,newMsg);
})



function messageEditEmbed(o,n){
    let channel = o.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "logs");

    if(channel){
        let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription(`***A message was edited by ${o.author} in ${o.channel}*** `)
        if(o){embed.addField("Before: ",o.content)}
        if(n){embed.addField("After: ",n.content)}
        channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

It should just turn smoothly as it does, but not crash...

Comment: Update: Seems like a issue regarding the library itself(?), I went into the source and commented the "throw new RangeError", it stopped the bot from crashing but still has a huge error claiming that a field can not be empty, although the message is sent.

Comment: The error it gives describes that a field value is empty, which is not allowed. Meaning that either `o.content` or `n.content` is empty. Can you confirm this is actually the case or not?

Comment: They both are filled, the embed is created, everything works, but eventually the bot crashes due to the error, which I tried commenting and didn't crash, yet outputed error. / http://prntscr.com/mfs46r

Comment: Oh, and, I've tried both those things, by adding if(n){} and if(o){} for that reason, in case for some reason it wasn't a thing, it wouldn't generate and break

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember the `const Discord = require('discord.js')`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that `o.content` or `n.content` is empty. This is natural when an message is changed and contents is removed/added.

One way to handle this, is not trying to add the field *if* the actual content is empty, and another way is to add a zero-width space in front of the potentially empty field, for example to do `\u200b${n.content}`.

Do note that `o` and `n` can exist and be non-empty, whilst `o.content` and `n.content` still are empty.